# Create an array of all possible sports scores (upto a limit)

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to automatically create an array of possible sport scores, such as 0-0, 1-2, 3-2, etc. Up to 15-15.

I'm have no idea how to do this, so I started doing this manually, but I'm sure there's a way to loop around and do this.

So far I have

```
$return = array(
            'first'  => array('0 - 1', '1 - 0'),
            'second' => array('1 - 1', '2 - 0', '0 - 2'),
            'third'  => array('2 - 1', '3 - 0', '1 - 2', '0 - 3'),
            'fourth' => array('3 - 1', '4 - 0', '2 - 2', '0 - 4', '1 - 3'),
            'fifth'  => array('4 - 1', '5 - 0', '3 - 2', '0 - 5', '2 - 3', '3 - 2', '1 - 4'),
            'sixth'  => array('5 - 1', '6 - 0', '4 - 2', '0 - 6', '3 - 3', '4 - 2', '1 - 5'), 
        );
```

But it's extremely tedious.

Comment: other than the first/second business, why not just two nested loops? `for(i=0; i<=15etc..) { for j (j=0 ; j<=15 etc...) }`?

Comment: I think i was overly complicating things. This was painfully obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming since you formatted your sample as such that you want the results in an array of arrays, in which each array contains the results with that many goals in it. That's pretty easy to do with double for loops.

```
$goals = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 16; $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < 16; $j++) { 
        if (!isset($goals[$j])) {
            $goals[$j] = array();
        }
        $goals[$i+$j][] = $i . " - " . $j;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like he wants each sub array from position x to have all  permutations of score with a total number of goals equaling x

Comment: No, I don't think so - the example given doesn't include previous scores in each new subarray.

Comment: The idea is to find out if 7 goals have been scored, what are the possible scores?

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest using the same loop but only adding to the ``$goals`` array ``if ($i+$j >= 7)``.